# nodejs proxy to redirect subdirectory to different port

Tags: node.js

My idea is to split the client static files and the nodejs server.
In production i will most likely serve the static files from nginx directly and proxy everything with an /api/ route to the node app.

In development I thought I can achieve the same by a simple nodejs app but i have no idea how to set this up. Currently my client files are serverd on port 9000 via a grunt dev server and the api is on port 3000. Is there an easy way to write a node app which redirects every request which doesn't start with /api/ to port 9000 and all other traffic to port 3000?

Comment: I tried the same thing with [node-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) but I didn't manage it. I ended with a local configuration with Apache mod_proxy but I think nginx is even easier to configure.

Comment: You can view my configuration at https://gist.github.com/hgoebl/7694751

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a nice grunt package which does the job:

```
grunt-connect-proxy
```